# how to completely filter a frequency range android

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, fft

I'm aware that `android.media.audiofx.Equalizer` can gain/lower frequency bands.What i need to do is to completely filter out a frequency range.Here is the code used to gain/lower the frequencies:

```
            Equalizer mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0,audioSessionId);
        mEqualizer.setEnabled(true);

        short bands = mEqualizer.getNumberOfBands();
        final short minEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
        final short maxEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[1];
        mEqualizer.setBandLevel((short) 0, (short) (maxEQLevel));
        mEqualizer.setBandLevel((short) 1, (short) (maxEQLevel));
//the following code wont work because setting levels.lower than minimum level is not acceptable
        mEqualizer.setBandLevel((short) 2, (short) (-1000000));
```

If what i asked for is impossible then what will you suggest?To write FFT classes from start?

Comment: Mathematically, it is impossible to completely remove a given frequency range.  You can only reduce it by an arbitrary amount.

Comment: Is it impossible to filter out all frequencies bigger than x hz?

Comment: Yes, the same argument applies.

Comment: Your best alternatives if the standard Equalizer doesn't attenuate the desired frequency bands enough are probably to either implement a band-stop filter that you run your audio through, or to do an FFT (where you've defined the frequency bins yourself) and heavily attenuate the bins that you want to suppress.

Comment: @Michael: Just attenuating individual bins is not going to give a good result, due to [Gibbs' phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_phenomenon).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Good to know. Since it would require extra processing to counter that effect it might not be viable for online use on a mobile device.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact implementation of the android equalizer you're suggesting, but if you have control over the actual filtering call (and not just the equalizer setup) you could call it a number of times on the same audio to attenuate even more. That would probably be sufficient if you goal is to make a frequency range non-audible. As other have mentioned there is no such thing as "completely remove" a frequency range. If you run the equalizer many times, Gibbs' phenomenon will still occur.

Comment: @KlausCPH thanks for your comprehensive comment.Gibbs' phenomenon seems to be in effect if we use FFT.I'm not sure if it applies to FIR or not.however what i neeed to implement is to make frequencies hard to hear(if not possible to completely wash them out).Im not the mathematics guy here.i just need a solution as a java/android programmer.i might need to use a FIR and not the android equalizer.i found some java dsp classes on github but not a comprehensive library and it seems i have a long run to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after lots of research,i found out that there is no native FIR methods for DSP purposes and i will have to either use android's built in Equalizer or implement my own FIR filter. Android's equalizer can only filter frequncy ranges and there is no way you setup a low pass filter.

Answer (score 2):

There are serious issues with Android’s equalizer and filters. They are not consistent across devices (on some devices not available at all), and they may perform poorly (high CPU load).

Although the filters are IIR, the notch or the parametric filter types can be configured for very steep cuts. In my cofounder's DJ app, djplayerapp.com, he can make cuts of -100 db with them.

Docs: http://superpowered.com/docs/class_superpowered_filter.html#details

Using the Superpowered Audio SDK you can have the highest performing filters designed for mobile devices, and they will work on all Android devices with the same audio quality.